# React Native support Display P3 color gamit ? or only srgb?

Tags: react-native, colors

When we were designing our app we used the sketch display P3 color profile, once we implemented everything in React Native we found that our colors were not the same as the ones designed they seem less lively. I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a solution to this?

Comment: I'm interested why did you choose to use P3 profile? As to the problem itself, this has nothing to do with react native

Comment: I guess because the colors look better, I mean UIColor has a color gamut parameter but RN doesn't so. my guess was that RN didnt support P3

Comment: I think you are a bit confused how color profiles work. Again this has nothing to do with `react-native` or coding. Maybe [this article](https://www.sketch.com/support/troubleshooting/color-management/) will help you understand the differences between color profiles :)

Comment: No, you wrong. In iOS p3 colors implementing in init(displayP3Red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat), but react native doesn't support this

Answer (score -1):

I have run into this too.  What I ended up doing was convert the colors in Sketch to the sRGB values making the app match the Sketch file.

In Sketch:

- Press ⌘+Shift+K This will pull up the color profile switcher
- Change the color profile to `sRGB`
- Click Change Profile
- Choose the Convert option (or assign if you want to assign RGB values)

You document should now be updated with the values you can use in your app that will match what you see on screen.

This article helped me https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/practical-colour-management-for-app-makers-2b5174c1b8cb

Comment: This solution will inherantly change the colors as sRGB is a smaller space by ~25% than P3.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's because you have the wrong color profile.